# based on which implementation does await and signalAll work

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, reentrantlock

I was reading about the `reentrantlock` in java and how we can know the lock condition by using the `newCondition()` method in the interface `Condition` but then I saw in the [documentation of the interface Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()) that the user has to provide an implementation for its use.

> Implementation Considerations:
>
> The current thread is assumed to hold the lock associated with this Condition when this   method is called. It is up to the **implementation** to determine if this is the case and if 
>       not, how to respond.

that being said since couple of days i was working on the dining philosopher problem and had to use signalAll() and await() without any self-provided implementation!.

per example i used this line:

```
((Philosopher) right).getNeighborCondition().await();
```

where the Object `right` is declared like this:

```
Iphilosopher right= new Philosopher();
```

`Iphilosopher` is an interface and the `Philosopher` is the class that implements it and extends `Thread`.

when clicking `Ctrl + left mouse click` on the method `await()` I'm presented with an interface void method which throws `InterruptedException`.

so which implementation is being used when `await()` or `signalAll()` are called?!

Comment: @Slaw `newCondition()`
Returns a new Condition instance that is bound to this Lock instance. my question is where is the implementation of the method `await()` to be found not what is the return value of the method `newCondition()` in the class `lock`!

Comment: @Slaw well, that explains it a bit. but would you please, add your comments as an answer with some references so others can still benefit from this question and your answer?! thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of the Javadoc is slightly incorrect. Here's the section of [`Condition#await()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await())'s Javadoc that you're focusing on:

> #### Implementation Considerations
>
> The current thread is assumed to hold the lock associated with this `Condition` when this method is called. It is up to the implementation to determine if this is the case and if not, how to respond. Typically, an exception will be thrown (such as `IllegalMonitorStateException`) and the implementation must document that fact.

This is saying three things:

1. The current thread must hold the lock when calling `await()`. This is further supported by the preceding documentation and the documentation of [`Lock#newCondition()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#newCondition()):

   > Before waiting on the condition the lock must be held by the current thread.
2. It is the responsibility of the `Condition` implementation to determine if the current thread holds the lock.
3. If the current thread does *not* hold the lock then what should happen is left unspecified.

   - It then goes on to say that a *typical* implementation will throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException` in such cases and that whatever approach is chosen must be documented by the implementation.

Nowhere does it say that the *user* must supply an implementation of `Condition#await()`. All it says is that the *developer* of a `Lock`, and by extension `Condition`, implementation must write the code to fit the contract, and provide the necessary documentation.

You mention `ReentrantLock`, which is a full implementation of `Lock`, so let's focus on that class. Here's an excerpt from the documentation of [`ReentrantLock#newCondition()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#newCondition()):

> - If this lock is not held when any of the `Condition` waiting or signalling methods are called, then an `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown.

This addresses point three above. This documentation states that the returned `Condition` instance will throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException` when `await()` (and each related method) is invoked by a thread which does not hold the lock.

But to answer your question directly: The implementation of `Condition` that's being used is whatever implementation is returned by `Lock#newCondition()`. You're not supposed to care about what exact type is returned as that's an implementation detail. Here's some related concepts:

- [Programming to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/6395627)
- [Factory methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

  - `Lock#newCondition()` is a factory method.

If you really want to know which implementation of `Condition` is used you can always look at the source code<sup>1</sup>. The `ReentrantLock` class currently uses instances of [`ConditionObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.ConditionObject.html).

---

<sup>1. *Warning:* The implementations of the `java.util.concurrent.locks` classes are non-trivial and deal with the intricacies of concurrency. But determining the implementation of `Condition` used should not be too difficult.</sup>